# How to create AIR native installer with AIR runtime

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, air

How can i create native installer for windows, MAC and linux, which will check the system if air runtime is not install in the user system then installer will 1st install the AIR runtime and then the AIR application.

Do we need to use any third party software to achicve this?

For checking system wether the AIR runtime is install or not Do we need to write custom script or installer will automatically get things done.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that, you could just provide AIR badge that is downloadable via websites. It automatically checks if the desktop has AIR installed or not, installs it and post that installs your normal non-native AIR application (.air file).

If you really wish not to use AIR badge, then you could google for arh tool which can do something similar - though I am not sure if AIR team recommends that. For more details, please refer:
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/756660